# Как сделать редирект  всех страниц на главную?

Tags: редирект, .htaccess, redirect

Как сделать редирект  всех страниц на главную?

Answer (score 4):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Так все запросы (в т.ч. и на ресурсы) будет перенаправляться на `index.php`. Для того, чтобы исключить ресурсы из передачи на index.php добавить директивы

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```