# редирект .htaccess на разные каталоги

Tags: .htaccess

[Как сделать редирект  всех страниц на главную?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/159766/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E/492232?noredirect=1#comment580173_492232)

Ребят как сделать тоже самое, но только если путь example/admin, редирект должен проиcходить на файл index.php в директории admin/

То есть если адрес example то редирект на index.php в корне
А если   example/admin или example/admin/тасиваси - то на файл index.php но в папке admin

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^example/admin/(.*)$ /admin/index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^example/$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

В данном случае при переходе по ссылке /example/admin/ и производных /example/admin/ххх пройдет переход на /admin/index.php. [L,QSA], L - означает что фаил htacces перестанет читаться после этого правила, если оно подходит. А QSA - что разрешена передача параметров.

Comment: в скобках .* - чет не могу нормально тест отформатить, L - заканчивает чтение файла если правило подходит

Comment: а точнее RewriteRule ^example/admin/(.)$ /admin/index.php [L,QSA]

Comment: Вот вам пример форматирования. Всё просто: 4 пробела в начале строки. Надеюсь, я ничего в процессе редактирования не убил, посмотрите :)

Comment: а. вот в чем дело) спасибо большое за помощ)

Comment: Ответ тревогнула система, как потенциально низкокачественный, иначе я б его не нашёл, хе. Возможно, его стоит расширить кратким описанием того, из чего состоят паттерны выше. Возможно, поставивший минус одумается, ведь ему целую единицу (ОУЖАС!) репутации пришлось за него отдать.

Comment: Я вот и хочу отформатировать, и более уточнить...если чесно только зарегистрировался и не знаю всех тонкостей...